# Quickbook invoice getting added twice through api

Tags: quickbooks

I am using Quickbook Online PHP SDK USING QBXML.

I am adding invoice through api.

quickbook is adding same invoice twice even though request is sended once.

as i have checked the response xml it is showing same invoice multiple times in single response.

How can i restrict quickbook to add invoice once as i am sending request once?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

> quickbook is adding same invoice twice even though request is sended once.

This is highly, highly unlikely. There are hundreds of thousands of people out there that use similar integrations, and you're the only one with this problem.

> as i have checked the response xml it is showing same invoice multiple times in single response.

Then you should post the qbXML request and qbXML response, so that we can verify what you're seeing, and so that if it *does* turn out to be a bug, we can report it to Intuit together with a verifiable way of reproducing it.

> How can i restrict quickbook to add invoice once as i am sending request once?

If you send a request once, you'll only get a response once. There's about a 99.99% chance that you're doing something wrong. If you're sure you're not, then post up your logs and qbXML request and response so we can verify it and help you out.